# How can I do to optimize my loop for using a condition if?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to optimize my python code using Django.

Here is my code :

```
a = 0
for item in items:
    if item != 'bag':
        a += 2
```

It is a basic example but what I would like is to avoid to loop on all the items.

Do you know if there is a solution ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: If you have a list of something, then you need to loop over it in order to do something for each item based on a condition. You may be able to dress up this loop in various ways, but you can't *avoid* it altogether. What's the issue with this code…?

Comment: What does this have to do with django?

Comment: `a = sum(2 for item in items if item != 'bag')`…

Answer (score 1):

Try count function:

```
a = (len(items) - items.count('bag')) * 2
```

Comment: I achieve with that :

```a = 0
for item in [x for x in items if x!= 'bag']:
    a += 2```